# php ajax call not returning anything if takes long time to return

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a database which has huge data like more than 1000 and it will increase later.

I show some of this data in a table. there is a searchbox which i am using to load data from database into that table using ajax call according to the searchbox.

my **FORM:**

```
<form class="form-search" role="search" action="#" >
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eml_search" placeholder="Search " name="eml_search">
       <input type="submit" name="btn-search-email" id="btn-search-email" value="" style="display: none;" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery Ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('form.form-search').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var eml_search_txt = $("#eml_search").val();
            url = "ajax_search.php";

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                data : {
                    eml_search_txt: eml_search_txt
                },
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log("Dhukse: " );
                $("#eml-body table").remove();
                console.log("TExt get: " + data.getext);
                console.log(data.mail_list);
                $("#eml-body").html(data.search_list);

            });
        });
    });
```

**ajax_search.php:**

```
include("connect.php");
$eml_search_txt = $_GET['eml_search_txt'];


$output = "";

$output .= "<table class='table table-striped table-inbox eml-overview' >";
$output .= "<thead>";
$output .= "<tr><th>Thead1</th><th>Thead2</th><th>Thead3</th></tr>";
$output .= "</thead>";
$output .= "<tbody>";


$search_query = "SELECT * FROM table_data WHERE data_from LIKE '%".$eml_search_txt."%' OR 
data_sub LIKE '%".$eml_search_txt."%' ORDER BY data_date DESC LIMIT 9 ";
$search_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $search_query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_sql)) {
    $data_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['data_date']));
    $uid = $row['uid'];
    $data_from = $row['data_from'];
    $data_sub = $row['data_sub'];

    $output.= "<tr>";
    $output.= "<td>".$data_from."</td>";
    $output.= "<td>".$data_sub."</td>";
    $output.= "<td>".$data_date."</td>";

    $output.= "</tr>";

}

$output .= "</tbody></table>";

$json='{"search_list":"'.$output.'", "getext":"'.$eml_search_txt.'"}';
print $json;
```

this ajax call on php file works fine if i limit the return upto 9 rows, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_data WHERE data_from LIKE '%".$eml_search_txt."%' OR 
data_sub LIKE '%".$eml_search_txt."%' ORDER BY data_date DESC LIMIT 9
```

But if want to return all the rows or more than 9 rows according to searchbox 
it does not returning me anything.

As far as i understand that, if ajax call takes long time to return data, it is returning nothing at all, such as returning all rows from database according to the search 
takes some times.

Can any one help me in this case ? how can i get all the result to show according to search?

Comment: Are you always returning only 9 rows?Have you tried larger limits of maybe 25 or 50?

Comment: yes, i have tried with more than 9 like 10 or 15.

Comment: Have you tried the call using the mysql console?Does it return more than 9 rows?

Comment: Yes, if i don't use LIMIT in mysql console, it returns more than 9

Answer (score 0):

You need optimize BD, for example add indexes on fields data_from, data_sub, data_date.
But it very strange, that this select call takes long time.

And you can set_time_limit to greater values.